# ElasticSearch Best approach for Searching a similar document

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I have a set of documents that each could be described as a list of unique words(features) `e.g. [12, 45, 56, 78, ...]`. The number of features is around 1k. Features contained in a document may appear in another document. I want to return the most similar documents. What would be the most efficient approach?

Answer (score 0):

You may straightforwardly try [this type of query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) and see how good it works for you. Just work out your, so to say, "highest-common-factor" reference doc to get most results.

P.S. If your terms ("features") are morphing in some way, it also make sense to look at [fuzzy queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html).

Comment: I actually thought of this but in the documentation I read that there is the max_query_terms variable which is maximum to 25. Given that the features are around 1000, wouldn't that end up really slow?